How to understand exponential in infinite Weierstrass product of $\sin(\pi z)$
Based on the discussion in Understanding infinite product of $sin(\pi z)$, I have a very rudimentary question: How do we derive the equation $\sin(\pi z) = \pi z \prod_{n\neq 0} (1-z/n)e^{z/n}$ in the first place? I don't really see how we get the $e^{z/n}$ term, when all the Weierstrass elementary functions contain a partial sum... Any clarification would be much appreciated!

Standard text book material. Almost any book on Complex Analysis has a  proof. Look for Hadamard Factorization Theorem.

Almost anywhere I searched it simply says: The formula follows directly from the Weierstrass factorization theorem. Since the zeros of $sin(\pi z)$ are the integers, I understand the (1-z/n) term. My question however is why the exponential term wouldn't be $e^{z/n+(z/n)^2/2+...+(z/n)^n/n}$, instead of simply $e^{z/n}$, according to the definition of Weierstrass elementary functions. Can you please help me to see what I'm missing?

There is section titled 'Factorization of the sine function' in Conway's book on Functions of a  Complex Variable.

Thank you! So in gist, we simply use the elementary function $E_1(z/n)$ for every factor, since the infinite sum over $1/n^2$ converges. That clears things up!
